# The register page is not taking the data it is showing success as false

Tags: mean-stack

[it is showing false instead of taking input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvfwx.png)

I want that register page will take the input and link and navigate to login page.
Even though I give input correctly it is not taking input and also not showing errori am doing in mern-stack technology,
Tell me which file I have to share.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.